# Reduce if/else-if on a bunch of partially overlapping conditions

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, theory, boolean-expression

I was trying to solve a coding problem which ended up with these conditionals:

```
x_A2 <= x_B1 OR x_A1 >= X_B2  --> 0
x_A1 <= x_B1 <= x_A2  --> x_A2 - X_B1
x_B1 <= x_A1 <= x_B2  --> x_B2 - X_A1
x_B1 <= x_A1 <= x_B2 AND x_B1 <= x_A2 <= x_B2  --> x_A2 - X_A1
x_A1 <= x_B1 <= x_A2 AND x_A1 <= x_B2 <= x_A2  --> x_B2 - X_B1
```

As you can see if I were to build 5 if/else-if statements, there are some computations that are repeated.

I'd like to know if there is a mathematical theory or procedure/algorithm to "reduce" or optimize any problem of the same kind.

I'm undecided if this was more of a math question.

Just to be more clear: I can start by any one of those "atomic conditions" and have two branches, one for True and one for False. But the starting point can be indeed any of those conditions and every branch contains the same structure just described.

Does this problem need an algorithm of its own involving graphs?

Comment: Understand that many of these comparisons are relatively inexpensive computationally. You could store the comparisons in a boolean array, and then simply reference those booleans, but I don't see that necessarily being better/more performant than simply doing a check twice. JIT may very well notice the repeated condition and optimize it for you anyhow. In my opinion: make the code clear first, then look for actual/realized performance issues. You may find further optimizations are possible if you reduce to CNF/DNF form, which I believe JIT will only try at some point for hard-hitting areas.

Comment: (To clarify: CNF/DNF reduction is NP-hard: it's "fast" to solve in human terms (seconds), but to a computer it is agonizingly slow and usually shouldn't be done on the fly except for small inputs or again, noticeably imperformant areas)

Comment: It is both mathematics and programming. You may think of formulas and then it's mathematics. Or you may think of a flow of a program and then it's programming. It's the different personalities the same actor plays. People are writing programs and then need to refactor their conditionalities if they get superfluous. So programmers actually need the knowledge you are asking for, therefore it's a programming question.

Comment: There are several of those conditions that can be true at the same time. For instance, when condition #4 is true, then #3 is true also. Even all conditions can be true at once (when all inputs are equal). It is not clear what you want to happen when more than one condition is true. Does order of evaluation matter? Is there some priority in those cases?

Comment: Seems like this is part of a deeper problem, but still not quite sure the terminology. Could you explain what, _eg_ `--> 0` or `--> x_A2 - X_A1` are supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have n statements, each i'th statement consists of f(i) sub-statements. Then, the statements of

```
s1
s2
.
.
.
sn
```

in a sense of if-else look like this:

```
s1
not (s1) and s2
not (s1 or s2) and s3
.
.
.
not (s1 or s2 ... or sn-1) and sn
```

So, if you are at si, you know that all the earlier statements were false.

Hence, you will know that some earlier statements have some truth-value, such as

T(A1), ... T(Am)

if any of the statements whose truth-value was determined in earlier ifs is a part of a later else if, then you can actually reuse it.

Example:

```
if A > 5
else if B > 2 and A <= 5
```

can be simplified to

```
if A > 5
else if B > 2
```

because by the time we have reached the else branch we already know that A > 5 is false. Furthermore, even

```
if A > 5
else if B > 2 and A <= 6
```

can be simplified to

```
if A > 5
else if B > 2
```

Because (not (A > 5)) => (A <= 6) and if we ever reach the else if, we already know that the premise, that is, that (not (A > 5)) is true.

So, as a result, we have the formula of whenever we know the truth values of

T(A1), T(A2), ..., T(Ai), ...

if we have a predicate P inside an else if where T(Ai) => P, then via modus ponens, we already know that P is true. Also, if we know that not T(Ai) => P, then via reductio ad absurdum we know that P is false.

Of course, you can use logic to make a composite statement of your knowledge so far, by applying logical relations or operations and combine new information.

For example, if we know that T(A1) is true and T(A2) is false, then we also know that (T(A1) and T(A2)) is false.

Also, you can apply other mathematical knowledge, such as transitivity of <= or so on. Let's take a look at your first statement:

```
x_A2 <= x_B1 OR x_A1 >= X_B2
```

It's a statement of X OR Y. We also know that X OR Y is false if and only if X OR Y is false. Therefore, if you ever reach an else if, then you know that X is false and Y is false. Therefore, if you are at the second statement, then you know that the first was evaluated as false, therefore x_A2 <= x_B1 is false. So its opposite is true, which is x_B1 < x_A2 therefore x_B1 <= x_A2 is also true.